# How to remove class from all child elements

Tags: jquery, html, attr

I have a html like:

```
<table id="message">
    <tr class="clsaa1">
        <td>
            <div class="class3">
                <table class="sub_1">
                ----------------------
                ----------------------
                </table>
            <div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clsaa2">
        <td>
            <div class="class3">
                ----------------------
                ----------------------
            <div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need to **remove all** `class` attributes inside `#message`.

I have tried

```
$('#message').siblings().removeAttr('class');
```

and

```
$('#message').children().removeAttr('class');
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 22):

A simple and elegant solution would be:

```
$(".class").removeClass("class");`
```

Comment: This is the simplest answer of them all to strip a class from an unknown set of elements!

Answer (score 10):

Older thread, but in my case I wanted to remove a specific class from all child elements

```
 $('#parentDiv').find("*").removeClass("row-selected");
```

Answer (score 9):

Instead of `removeAttr('class')` you can use `removeClass("classname")`

If you want to remove all the class values from its children, then do like

```
$('#message').find("*").prop("class","");
```

or even

```
$('#message').find('*') removeAttr('class');
```

Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kyLYD/1/).

Comment: I want to remove some other attributes in the same manner,Not only class.

Comment: I dont know the class name also.Remove all class

Comment: this wont work, you need to iterrate over the childrens children.

Comment: With $('#message').find('*') removeAttr('class'); is also working

Answer (score 2):

You need to use find to grab all the nested elements, then iterrate over them.

```
$('#message').find('*').each(function(){
     $(this).removeAttr('class');
})
```

Comment: I can't predict the class names

Comment: @shijin there you go updated my answer, let me know if it works.

Comment: I got "SyntaxError: Unexpected token *" Error

Comment: @shijin jus twrap the start in '*'

Comment: This works, just had to change `removeAttr` to `removeClass`.

Answer (score 0):

It will work fine

```
    $('#message').find('*').removeAttr('class');
```